# How to convert number leading zero to string and retain the original number

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert number lead by 0 to string.

for example

**var x = 01127160037**

but when I convert it to string, it become **157081631**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = 01127160037;
  var res = x.toString();
  console.log(res)
}
myFunction();
</script>
```

I'm expecting to get actual result as "01127160037" in string.

Comment: *"With leading zero, you use octal numbers."* it's even worse, because that is only true if the number does only contain `0..7` as digits. otherwise it is interpreted as decimal. My takaway: don't use numbers with leading zeroes; **at all**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With leading zero, you use [octal numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#Octal_numbers). To get decimals, you need to convert back to octals and take this string.

If you got a value which can not be an octal number, check if the stringed value contains eight or nine and take this value without conversion instead.

```js
const convert = n => '0' + (/[89]/.test(n.toString())
        ? n.toString()
        : n.toString(8)
    );

console.log(convert(01127160037));
console.log(convert(01127160038));
```

Comment: try `01127160038`. that thing with the leading zero as octal-notation was ... unfortunate