# How can i ignore the javascript convert leading zero to octal?

Tags: javascript

I want to convert `number` to `string`, buti have a problem about javascript convert number that have leading zero to octal.

I have a list of object like this

```
const ids = [
  { _id : 1236 },
  { _id : "abc123" },
  { _id : 012019 },
  { _id : 000010 },
  { _id : 001230 }
  { _id : 00000000000000 }
]
```

and i want to convert all of id in object to `string` 
like this

```
[
  { _id : "1236" },
  { _id : "abc123" },
  { _id : "012345" },
  { _id : "000010 },
  { _id : "001230" },
  { _id : "00000000000000" }
]
```

So, i write a function like this

```
updateIds = () => ids.map(i => {
  i._id = i._id.toString()
  return i
})

updateIds()
```

But the result of this function is ..

```
[
  { _id: '1236' },
  { _id: 'abc123' },
  { _id: '012019' },
  { _id: '8' },
  { _id: '664' },
  { _id: '0' }
]
```

how can i ignore javascript convert `000010` and `001230` to octal ?

Ps. I think i cant use `pad` function to write leading zero because value of `_id` is dynamic. i don't know that length.

Comment: you could have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58336825/1447675

Comment: btw, leading zeros are gone after converting.

Comment: _“I have a list of object like this”_ - as actual JS _code_? Then you lose your original values at the time of parsing already - log that to console, and you’ll see that `000010` has become `8` already. You would need to handle this as _text_ and write your own parser for it …

Comment: Where does that array of ids come from? Is it generated somewhere? If so, you should adapt the code to generate the `_id` values as strings to begin with.

Comment: its come from value in `csv` file.

Comment: How do you do the transformation from CSV to the object structure that you have in your question? It's in that bit of code that I recommend you to make a change so that the id values will remain as string instead of numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the base you want to use in the `toString` call.

If you want the ids to be parsed as base 10, then called `toString(10)`. It's impossible to do the padding to preserve the length because numbers are numbers, so leading zeros are ignored. You can pad to a fixed length, for all the ids:

```
updateIds = () => ids.map(i => {
  i._id = i._id.toString(10).padStart(9, '0');
  return i
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Constructor call `Number("001230")`. It will convert all numbers to `base 10` only, so you won't have the `octal` conversion problem

```
const ids = [
  { _id : 1236 },
  { _id : "abc123" },
  { _id : 012019 },
  { _id : 000010 },
  { _id : 001230 },
  { _id : 00000000000000 }
];

let ans = [];

ids.forEach((val)=>{

    let obj = {};
    obj._id = Number(val["_id"]);
    ans.push(obj);

})

console.log(ans);
```

Comment: _“Use Constructor call Number("001230")”_ - only that’s not possible here, because you do not have that value `001230` any more. Log `ids` to console, and you will see that `001230` has become `664` in there already. This happens at the step of _parsing_ the object literal already.